# Send Json Payload to californium server

Tags: c

I am using the development kit nrf9160 from Nordic Semiconductor. The server hostname in my code is "californium.eclipseprojects.io" and peer "5684".

I want to send a JSON payload using the PUT-method from CoAP. For this I am creating my JSON Payload with the following function:

```
{
   cJSON *root = cJSON_CreateObject();
   cJSON_AddNumberToObject(root, "JSON", 50);
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(root, "Content-Form", 12);
     return root;
}
```

The main function:

```
 cJSON_Init();
 cJSON *item = createJsonFromParams();
 char *payload=cJSON_Print(item);
```

What I am sending is this:

```
{
  "JSON": 50,
  "Content-Form": 12
}
```

And what the server gets is : `"{\n\t"`

Can someone please help and tell me, why is it like that? Is this the appropriate way of sending the JSON Payload?

Comment: Which language are you actually using: C or C++?  And why have you tagged this with the other one?

Comment: Hi @ScottHunter,

i am using C language

Comment: the missing part is, where you set "char *payload" as payload for your coap-message. I guess, the length provided there, is wrong. So, provide that snippet as well.

Comment: Hi @AchimKraus,

'coap_packet_append_payload(&request, (uint8_t *)payload, sizeof(payload)-1);'

That's the function i am using to set the payload for the coap request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of

```
cJSON_Init();
cJSON *item = createJsonFromParams();
char *payload=cJSON_Print(item);
```

will be a common C-string  with a \000 byte to terminate the string.

```
coap_packet_append_payload(&request, (uint8_t *)payload, sizeof(payload)-1);
```

is a snippet, which usually is used with an array definition in the same scope as the sizeof.

```
char payload[] = "I'm a array";

printf("sizeof %d, strlen %d\n", sizeof(payload), strlen(payload));
```

that prints:

sizeof 12, strlen 11

because sizeof contains the trailing \000, strlen not.

If you use sizeof for pointer, as

```
char *payload=cJSON_Print(item);
printf("sizeof %d, strlen %d\n", sizeof(payload), strlen(payload));
```

the result will be the sizeof the pointer (depending on your cpu architecture) and the length of the returned JSON string.

sizeof 4, strlen n

you now reduce the wrong by 1 (as it would be ok for an array), which result in 3. What you need to do to fix it:

```
coap_packet_append_payload(&request, (uint8_t *)payload, strlen(payload));
```

Please be aware: C has many pitfalls, here, don't forget to free the payload after your ready. If you fall in such a the pitfal, you application will get unstable.

Comment: Hi @AchimKraus

thank you for your answer and explanations